# C# Cannot connect to my Async TCP Server

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have an async TCP server I built that acts as an intermedium between a remote client application and the SQL server. Anyway, when I go to test a connection from a remote machine - it won't connect. I am using Putty to test the connection to the TCP server and Putty immediately closes after I push connect. I set up Wireshark on both machines and I see some sort of communication come through on the port from the source IP but I don't know how to read it. Both machines are Windows and I turned off the Windows Firewall. Can anyone help me diagnose my issue? Thanks.

Here's my Async Server code: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ELyBNp68)

Here's my Wireshark Capture (Server Side): [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/kCrs9Yu3)

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup putty to use raw tcp connections as explained in the [documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-rawprot) of putty?

By default, putty creates secure shell (ssh) connections.

Comment: For the future, when you make a question to an user, would be better than you did it in the comments instead of an answer.

Comment: Yes I did try in Telnet and Raw - both result in the same quick shut down of Putty

Comment: Figured it out. Simple misunderstanding of the MSDN example of TcpListener. Needed to set it to IPAddress.Any not local. Thanks guys.